# JIRA JQL: How to search for issue with particular component alone?

Tags: search, jira, jql

I'd like to search for issues which have component A alone not but A + B, A + C, A + N and so on...

Taking into account that I may not know all the combinations A + N to list them in the "not in" black list and also that it would be good to avoid updating searches every time new combination is used.

Comment: Please clarify. If you don't know what the components to exclude are how can you exclude them?

Comment: Yes, question is, is exclusion the only way here? Is there a way to say "I want issues with component A only"?

Comment: What is the use case? Maybe you are using the wrong approach here, or misusing JIRA's component concept

Comment: I'm trying to represent layers and functional areas in the system using JIRA components, let's say I have layers "UI", "REST" and areas "Forum" and "Search". I'm planning to use single components and combinations of components such as "Search", "Search" + "UI", "Search" + "REST" and so on. At some point I need to search for "Search" only to get issues related to core component only (backend), not "REST" or "UI". In reality I will have more layers and areas, and lots of saved searches and agile boards.

Comment: CONTINUE: I can't really know all of the combinations upfront, as new components may be added on the go, and I don't want to update many searches each time is happens.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not a built in way of doing this. It might be possible for you to add it yourself through a [JQL extension](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/search/tutorial-adding-a-jql-function-to-jira). Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

What I believe you are saying is known are all components A thru N, but not all of the combinations of components used. If that is the case, we can exclude all of the components we do not want and only include the one we do, like so:

`Components = A AND Components not in (B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, N)`

This will show only those Jiras that have only the A component.

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-searching-179442050.html#AdvancedSearching-Component

Comment: Thanks Rich! I think I have found out this solution already, but I'm looking if there is a way to not list all other components, because it's too much routine.

Comment: Hi Anton, I think this is going to be the only way to do this within the Issue Search parameters. I believe you may be able to do what you are seeking using a tool like Adaptavist Script Runner or using the API. Unfortunately, that is a little out of my domain. :)

Comment: Thanks anyway, Rich!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Chris, I think it is not possible, and i don`t know any plugin that supports that. 
If is something really important and mandatory, i used to combine Jira and Excel usage for achiving this kind of tricky stuff:

- use your JQL expresion: `component = yourComponent`
- Export your search to Excel
- Once in excel create some filter on Component column like: text filter>does not contain ","
- now that you have filter wich are with just one component, copy all your showed results, and paste them in another sheet.
- Finally filter your component column again, this time selecting just yourComponent.

It is a bit long proccess, but this way you ccan quickly search what you need.

Tip: you can automatize this proccess, using macros and formules.

Hope to help,

Regards

Comment: Thanks! Although I want to build queries not for analysis only but also for Agile boards, so Excel doesn't really help here.